# CVS writerow() after expression

Tags: python, regex, csv

I haven't been able to re.sub a csv file.
My expression is doing it's job but the writerow is where I'm stuck.

```
re.sub                   out
"A1","Address2"          "A1","Address2"
0138,"DEERFIELD AVE"     0138,"DEERFIELD"
0490,"REMMINGTON COURT"  0490,"REMMINGTON"
2039,"SANDHILL DR"       2039,"SANDHILL"

import csv
import re

with open('aa_street.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    read=csv.reader(f)  
    for row in read:
        row_one = re.sub('\s+(DR|COURT|AVE|)\s*$', ' ', row[1])
        row_zero = row[0]
        print row_one

    for row in reader:
        print writerow([row[0],row[1]])
```

Comment: You are trying to read from the same file *twice*; the file will already have been read by `read`, so `reader` won't find any more rows.

Comment: Why did you edit this and do nothing but break the formatting/indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you need?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

# "A1","Address2"          "A1","Address2"
# 0138,"DEERFIELD AVE"     0138,"DEERFIELD"
# 0490,"REMMINGTON COURT"  0490,"REMMINGTON"
# 2039,"SANDHILL DR"       2039,"SANDHILL"

import re
import csv

with open('aa_street.txt', 'r') as infile, open('actual-output', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        row_zero = row[0]
        row_one = re.sub('\s+(DR|COURT|AVE|)\s*$', '', row[1])
        writer.writerow([row_zero, row_one])
```

Answer (score 2):

A file is an iterator—you iterate over it once, and then it's empty.

A `csv.reader` is also an iterator.

In general, if you want to reuse an iterator, there are three ways to do it:

1. Re-generate the iterator (and, if its source was an iterator, re-generate that as well, as so on up the chain)—in this case, that means `open` the file again.
2. Use `itertools.tee`.
3. Copy the iterator into a sequence and reuse *that* instead.

In the special case of files, you can fake #1 by using `f.seek(0)`. Some other iterators have similar behavior. But in general, you shouldn't rely on this.

Anyway, the last one is the easiest, so let's just see how that works:

```
reader = list(csv.reader(f))
read = reader
```

Now you've got a list of all of the rows in the file. You can copy it, loop over it, loop over the copy, close the file, loop over the copy again, it's still there.

Of course the down side it that you need enough memory to put the whole thing in memory (plus, you can't start processing the first line until you've finished reading the last one). If that's a problem, you need to either reorganize your code so it only needs one pass, or re-open (or `seek`) the file.

Comment: why is I can iterate through a file using replace() easily but not the expression re.sub?

Comment: @George: I have no idea what you mean by that question, or what it has to do with either your main question or my answer.